# Swift Version Conflict: this SDK is not supported by the compiler, Please select a toolchain which matches the SDK

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, conflict

I'm using xCode 13.1 with macOS 12.0.1 Monterey. I added `KingFisher` and removed it from my pod. but my project is not built anymore. I got this error for one of my local SDKs:

```
Failed to build module 'CbSdk';
this SDK is not supported by the compiler (the SDK is built with 'Apple Swift version 5.4
(swiftlang-1205.0.26.9 clang-1205.0.19.55)', while this compiler is 'Apple Swift version 5.5.1 
(swiftlang-1300.0.31.4 clang-1300.0.29.6)'). Please select a toolchain which matches the SDK.
```

What I've done but didn't work:

- `pod deintegrate` and `pod install`.
- restart xCode with clearing cache and `DerivedData`.
- checkout old branch and commit that worked before.
- moving code to another macBook that worked before.
- download, install and select toolchain 5.4 (odd errors appeared -> )
- changing swift compiler language of my target and project to swift 4 (It says you are using swift 5.5.1 again!)
- note that I didn't update xcode or swift!

Comment: Same Problem I have. Did you find the solution?

Comment: Finally, I reported to the developer team, and they released an updated version. That wasn't a problem that I could fix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taken from this Twitter thread.

You need to set the BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION build setting on the framework target

https://www.swift.org/blog/library-evolution/

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/416/

[image]

Comment: How change BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION for a locally added SDK?

Comment: @MahdiMoqadasi, you can't - unless you control and build that SDK. If it is a 3rd party SDK that does not belong to you, you have no control over it.

Comment: @TJOlsen Thanks. you're right. Finally, I reported to the developer team, and they released an updated version. This wasn't a problem that I could fix.

Comment: @MahdiMoqadasi Correct, but you did exactly what you DID have the power to do, so I'll point it out here in case it helps anyone in the future - you reported the issue to the dev team in charge of the SDK in use. For anyone in the future - submit an issue to the SDK dev team in question and at least just ask if they have Build for distribution set to `yes`. That is a great starting place.

Answer (score 4):

I fetch the same problem when I try to update a library. My Xcode version was `13.2` with the swift version`5.5.2`. But the library I want to update required a swift version `of 5.7.0`. Using toolchains in Xcode might be the solution but I decided to update the Xcode version with the latest.

I update my Xcode to the latest version `14.1` and the issue is resolved. Automatically the swift version is found on the latest Xcode.

Comment: always use the latest xcode.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I'm developing a Framework that uses 3rd party Swift Packages internally. Originally, I thought this error was being thrown because I upgraded to Xcode 15. Turns out, it was completely unrelated.

If you are using 3rd party libraries and want to export a Framework, you must include the "**@_implementationOnly**" tag in front of the imports.

**Example: "@_implementationOnly import BoltsSwift".**

If you do this, it will not include these 3rd party library imports in the binary modules within the framework. This is great because the users of your framework don't care about the 3rd party libraries used in the back-end. Hope this helps at least one person! I rarely see anything online about the @_implementationOnly tag.

Comment: Just to note that this is experimental only https://forums.swift.org/t/update-on-implementation-only-imports/26996/29 and is mentioned here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0409-access-level-on-imports.md